# Hide product title and categories on product page

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, woocommerce

How could I hide product title and categories on a single product page in WooCommerce:
[image]

I know I can edit/comment the source code but then I have to manually do it after each update. Is there a function I can add to theme functions.php that can remove product title and categories from single product page?

Answer (score 6):

For compatibility with future updates of your theme and plugins, I've found a better way to do this is through *WooCommerce hooks*. To remove both the title and the meta-data items from your Single Product Page, you should put the following two lines in your theme's main **functions.php**:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );
```

You can find more info about changing, or re-ordering your Product Page Contents in [this post](http://wpbackoffice.com/reorder-product-page-contents-woocommerce/).

Answer (score 1):

Simplest Solution is go to woocommerce plugin /templates/single-product/title.php and remove content of this file.

Same process can be done by removing content of meta file in same directory.

Comment: You shouldn't edit a plugin directly because next time you update that plugin, your edit will be gone.

Comment: That is a very bad practice!!

Comment: Those files from `woocommerce/template` are copied to `yourtheme/woocommerce` so they override templates of the plugin.